# Global developers key in Canvas LMS

Tags: canvas-lms

I still have legacy support for canvas integration.
We use global developer keys
Question. where were these global keys set?
Yes. I have the values of these keys. but where did they come from?
where can i see them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link
https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Canvas-Admin-Blog/Administrative-guidelines-for-managing-Inherited-Developer-Keys/ba-p/269029

We do not have place where we can see global developer keys and icon url.

> Before October 2015
>
> Account-bound Developer Keys did not exist, so if a vendor wanted API
> access, we had to work with them to issue a global/inherited developer
> key.

It is mean that before OCT 2015 It was not possible create developer keys and icon URL directly in canvas lms account. Developer had to request canvas’s support and they issued developers key
This means that there is no place where we can edit these global keys and icon url. The only way to do this is to make a direct request to support

> Q: "Where do the Inherited Developer Keys originate?"
>
> A: Instructure issues them. See the “History” section above for more
> info.